# Deploying .env file with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables, capistrano, capistrano3

I want to upload `.env` file to my remote machine from local machine while deploying with Capistrano, but as I am not a Ruby pro I do not get the result I want. What I want to do is take my local `.env` and make it available on remote machine in the `shared_path`. Afterwards, just symlink it with the `current_path`.

```
namespace :env do
  desc "We take local env and set up on remote"
  task :setup do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do  
      puts File.read(".env"), "#{shared_path}/config/.env"

      execute "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/.env #{current_path}/.env"
    end
  end
end
```

Now this code creates .env as an empty file. What I am doing wrong? Or should I just execute `rsync` or something with Capistrano in order to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `puts` will work there.

Try the capistrano's [upload method](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Action-File-Transfer-Upload).

`upload(from, to, options={}, &block)`

Comment: Thanks. This helped!